# UINavigationBar cutting the height of status bar

Tags: ios, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, uinavigationbar

In iOS8, I have a root view controller where I would show another navigation view controller as the root vc's subview when user clicks on one button. I pre-loaded the navigation view controller in viewDidAppear to ensure responsiveness when user clicks on the button, since instantiating and adding subview would cause some latency.

However, if I put the setupNavigationVC() inside viewDidAppear(), my navigation bar would look like this when expanded to full screen.

[image: werid looking navigation bar with truncated height]

if I let my code execute setupNavigationVC() right after user clicks the button, the navigation bar would look normal.

Also, I noticed that if I pause the app and then go back in. The navigation bar would return to normal. I suppose the OS must have reloaded every view when an app is resumed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are added custom navigation bar then it should be at 20 pixels on Y position.

Comment: It is not a custom nav bar. Its the navigation bar that came with the navigation view controller. I am using the view controller mainly to take advantage of its back/forward button and gesture.

Comment: I think. When you showing the keyboard then it creates problem.

Comment: Good catch. Keyboard was causing me some weirdness but now I only call keyboard after the navigation view controller is expanded to full screen, so it shouldn't cause any layout problems anymore. It looks like this with or without the keyboard showing

Comment: May be. Problem solved ?